# paramiko-expect how to use when multi level auth involved

Tags: python, expect, paramiko

**Question in Short:**

is it possible to use paramiko-expect when multilevel authentication required.
My first level auth gets connected successfully, but unable to provide username it just timeout the connection

```
# Connect to the host
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=login, password=password1)
interact = SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=10, display=True)
interact.expect(prompt1)
interact.send('username')
interact.expect(prompt2)
interact.send(password2)
interact.expect()
cmd_output = interact.current_output_clean
```

Above gives a time put error

**Question in Detail:**

Currently this is what is do in Putty on windows on daily basis.

Click on my host then it prompts me like this, yes it has two level authentication.

```
login as:      loginName(Then enter)
Password:   Password1(Then enter)
Username:  UserName(Then enter)
Password:   Password2(Then enter)
Then one more  Enter

Here I get my Required output shown on Putty , this is just a couple line of text which usually gets changed everyday.
So i need to capture this on a daily basis.
```

I am not sure is this the right way to write my code.
I am sure it gets connected to hostname on level 1, but second level username is not passed. So not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import traceback
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Set SSH key parameters to auto accept unknown hosts
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

hostname = 'MyCustomServer.com'
login = 'myFirstLevelLogin'
password1 = 'MyFirstPassword'
username = 'mySecondLevelLogin'
password2 = 'MySecondPassword'
prompt1 = 'Username:'
prompt2 = 'Password:'


# Connect to the host
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=login, password=password1)

# Create a client interaction class which will interact with the host
interact = SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=10, display=True)
interact.expect(prompt1)
interact.send('username')
interact.expect(prompt2)
interact.send(password2)
interact.expect('Not sure what to put here as i just press enter in my usual putty session ')
interact.send('I send enter key')
interact.expect('This is my final output its two lines of text no command prompt here(i mean the typical user@mymachine:$) this will not be found, this screen goes off after 5 seconds')

cmd_output = interact.current_output_clean

# Send the exit command and expect EOF (a closed session)
interact.send('exit')
interact.expect()

print (cmd_output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on a project where it had to log in using username/password over SSH then do the same thing again to another host. I had no control over networks ACLs and SSH keys were not allowed for some reason. Here's how I got it to work:

```
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction

user1 = 'admin'
pass1 = 'admin'
user2 = 'root'
pass2 = 'root'

# not needed for this example, but included for reference
user_prompt = '.*\$ '   

# will match root user prompt
root_prompt = '.*$ '

# will match Password: or password:
pass_prompt = '.*assword: '

# SSH to host1
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='host1', username=user1, password=pass1)

# Interact with SSH client
with SSHClientInteraction(ssh_client, display=True) as interact:
    # Send the command to SSH as root to the final host
    interact.send('ssh {}@host2'.format(user2)
    # Expect the password prompt
    interact.expect(pass_prompt)
    # Send the root password
    interact.send(pass2)
    # Expect the root prompt
    interact.expect(root_prompt)

ssh_client.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, My case is little different. In my case I did not have to specify the expect line. I had to send the values straight away. I am accepting your answer as you have specified complete example.